# Export contents of block ram to a file in Xilinx FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, bram

Assume I have a simple adder Verilog code which does

sum=a+b

This code is implemented on a Xilinx FPGA (Basys3).
At every posedge of clock, I change a and b. I get sum. I run this simulation for 10000 clock cycles. I want to dump this output at every posedge of clock to a file for postprocessing.

Basically, I want to do an equivalent of the following:

always @(posedge clock)

$fwrite(a,b,sum)

I can obviously not synthesise fwrite and there is no filesystem interface with the FPGA. So, I am storing a,b,sum to a block RAM at every posedge of clock.
Now, I want to read this content or export this block RAM content to a file. That is, all 10000 lines (from 10000 clock edges) need to be read from the block RAM to a file. I use Xilinx Vivado and a Basys3 FPGA. Request someone to shed some light on this.

I tried using ILA without the BRAM- but when I use the export option through ILA in Vivado, it just stores the a,b,sum at a single trigger point, and not all all clock edges.

Is there some other way I can read out the content of this BRAM to a file?

Comment: This is not what FPGAs are meant to do.  If you are uncertain of the result use simulation or spot checks with the logic analyzer.  If this were a real need where it made sense to use an FPGA you would drive some output interface that made sense.

Comment: I understand this is not what FPGAs are meant to do. I am obviously not doing just sum=a+b. As a real application, I have a test circuit on the fpga, on which I am doing fault injection experiments. I need to record its output during fault injection. I have 10000 fault injections, so I need to store this data somewhere. Thats where I am coming from.

Comment: *"I tried using ILA without the BRAM- but when I use the export option through ILA in Vivado, it just stores the a,b,sum at a single trigger point, and not all all clock edges."* This should have worked. You probably didn't have the capture/trigger settings quite right. Can you provide more details about what you did here?

Comment: Used solution from https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/how-to-export-Vivado-ILA-data-to-excel-spread-sheet/td-p/663947 
write_hw_ila_data -force -csv_file foo.csv
We are able to export data and view it, but the number of samples is limited to 1024. But, my original question of how to obtain Block RAM data to a file still remains.

Comment: You could use something like this to access the block RAM over a serial port or over Ethernet: https://github.com/alexforencich/xfcp